# pip uninstall fails with "owned by OS" - even under sudo

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'm working on a DevOps project for a client who's using Python. Though I never used it professionally, I know a few things, such as using virtualenv and pip - though not in great detail.

When I looked at the staging box, which I am trying to prepare for running a functional test suite, I saw chaos. Tons of packages installed globally, and those installed inside a virtualenv not matching the requirements.txt of the project. OK, thought I, there's a lot of cleaning up. Starting with global packages.

However, I ran into a problem at once:

```
➜  ~ pip uninstall PyYAML
Not uninstalling PyYAML at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

OK, someone must've done a 'sudo pip install PyYAML'. I think I know how to fix it:

```
➜  ~ sudo pip uninstall PyYAML
Not uninstalling PyYAML at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

Uh, apparently I don't.
A search revealed some similar conflicts caused by users installing packages bypassing pip, but I'm not convinced - why would pip even know about them, if that was the case? Unless the "other" way is placing them in the same location pip would use - but if that's the case, why would it fail to uninstall under sudo?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it as root? There have been times where sudo hasn't been enough and I had to `sudo su` it

Comment: Huh? never heard of such a thing, always though sudo is equivalent to 'sudo su' approach. Nope, didn't work, same message.

Comment: [There's a bit more info on it here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592825/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-and-changing-to-root)

Comment: If you use virtualenv, why do you even bother to delete global packages? Do you experience any issues with these packages in your project?

Comment: not really (or not yet?), @AndriyMaletsky - I suppose I shouldn't worry too much. But being new to this stack I'm just a little bit paranoid =)

Comment: system packages and virtualenv packages don't interfere. But cleaning rubbish out of your system is definitely a good thing to do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pip denies to uninstall these packages because Debian developers patched it to behave so. This allows you to use both `pip` and `apt` simultaneously. The "original" pip program doesn't have such functionality

*Update:* my answer is relevant only to old versions of Pip. For the latest versions, Pip is configured to modify only the files which reside only in its "home directory" - that is `/usr/local/lib/python3.*` for Debian. For the latest tools, you will get these errors when you try to delete the package, installed by `apt`:

For `pip 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1` (installed from Ubuntu repository):

```
Not uninstalling pyyaml at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
```

For `pip 10.0.1` (original, installed from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org)):

```
Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: The two kinds of "Not uninstalling" messages I can find in regular pip come from [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/729990c9869148f3f0098a2b2a0c0b92aefb8a69/src/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py#L273); neither of them say "owned by OS", and "owned by OS" doesn't appear anywhere in the pip repository. I'm not sure where to find the Debian version.

Comment: I believe this version can be found here: https://packages.debian.org/en/source/stretch/python-pip

Comment: I believe it has something to do with this patch: https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/modules/python-pip/blob/master/debian/patches/hands-off-system-packages.patch

Answer (score 5):

The point is not that `pip` cannot install the package because you don't have enough permissions, but because it is not a package installed through `pip`, so it doesn't want to uninstall it.

`dist-packages` is where packages installed by the OS package manager reside; as they are handled by another package manager (e.g. `apt` on Ubuntu/Debian, `pacman` on Arch, `rpm`/`yum` on CentOS, ... ) `pip` won't touch them (but still has to know about them as they are installed packages, so they *can* be used to satisfy dependencies of `pip`-installed packages).

You should also probably avoid to touch them unless you use the correct package manager, and even so, they may have been installed automatically to satisfy the dependencies of some program, so you may not remove them without breaking it. This can usually be checked quite easily, although the exact way depends from the precise Linux distribution you are using.

Comment: In other words, no don't do that.

Comment: thank you sir, your explanation does make sense. however, it's very strange (and I did mention it in the question too):
*what* prevents pip from deleting them, if not file permissions? does it keep some form of a log of stuff it can touch, to distinguish from stuff it can't touch?